# writing a personal blog in PHP

Tags: php, blogs

Has anyone actually written a blog in PHP? If yes do you use frameworks? I am a beginner in PHP, but have developed in PHP... not sure if I should dive into frameworks just yet. I would like to build a personal blog my self using PHP just to use the skills and knowledge that I know, but don't know where to start

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is your question "Should I use a framework while I learn PHP or wait until I can do things for myself before depending on other people's libraries?"

Comment: Sorry, I added more details to the question above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I (along with most of the PHP community) have created many PHP blogs, some with and some without the aid of a framework. I think you shouldn't start with a framework and you **definitely** shouldn't confuse yourself with the complexities of Wordpress.
I believe in understanding before implementing. First learn how to code a blog from scratch. Once you understand and can code this, then learn a framework (such as CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Kohana). The framework will speed the development process up quite a bit, and after having to code everything from scratch you will truly be able to appreciate the benefits of a framework. With your deep understanding, you will also be able to expand on your blog's functionality.
Some may argue that I am proposing that you run before you walk. But I argue that if you walk with a crutch from the start, you will never be able to run or even walk on your own.

Comment: I like your suggestion very much... however, there isn't many resource out there that would help me to create a blog from scratch using PHP

Comment: Really? http://codegrrl.com/category/tutorials/build-a-blog   Google is your friend: http://www.google.com/search?q=creating+a+php+blog+from+scratch

Comment: I did use google, however none of them are good... the best that I can find is from NetTuts, but then there is no part 2 to it http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-an-object-oriented-blog-using-php/

Comment: @EquinoX What more do you require beyond the scope of the nettuts+ tut?

Answer (score 2):

A blog is the demo app for virtually every PHP framework out there. Tens of thousands of people have written blogs in PHP. Some 30 million people also run their blogs on WordPress, which is written in PHP.

Comment: I'd argue that blogs are the new "hello world" of any web technology :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, well first of all, writing a ***good*** custom CMS system is hard. I would first recommend you to make a [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) blog and a custom theme, then try [Movable Type](http://www.movabletype.org/), then try to create you own using [Cake PHP](http://cakephp.org/) if you feel like it. If you really want to code it yourself, Good Luck.

Comment: I disagree. Writing a custom CMS is one of the most common tutorials used throughout beginner-level PHP books. You can't get much easier than a CRUD app. It's what you'll end up writing if you go through "Build Your Own Database Driven Website Using PHP & MySQL" for example.

Comment: @Dan: maybe he meant time consuming, I am writing CMS for my living and let's say it's more complex then a tic tac toe game! After, I kind of agree with other answers, why reinvent the wheel especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: What is actually Movable Type?

Comment: I thought Moveable Type was a perl thing?!

Comment: @middus nope: https://github.com/movabletype/movabletype/blob/master/php/mt.php

Comment: @Bobby Jack But all the backend stuff is still perl.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is written in PHP, you can start there.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://www.youtube.com/user/andrewperk) blog tutorial for cake php framework. Very nice. 15 videos and you will the basic ground.

Answer (score 0):

Well,for personal blog , in above every one said that Wordpress  is the best .yes it is.Wordpress  is written in php .In wordpress have custom CMS by that you can easily customize your blog .Most important thing is that Wordpress have also responsive too .So you can easily open you site from any device